# Number plus a number is NaN in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am fuming over how stupid this is. How is this possible?

```
  console.log(typeof form.timeCompletedInSeconds);
  console.log(typeof totalTimeCompletion);

  console.log(totalTimeCompletion);
  console.log(form.timeCompletedInSeconds);

  totalTimeCompletion = form.timeCompletedInSecond + totalTimeCompletion;
  console.log(totalTimeCompletion)
```

Output:

```
number
number
0
3
NaN
```

Comment: Please create an executable code snippet of the issue..

Comment: Can you please produce an [mcve]? Use the Stack snippet tool while [edit]ing your question to provide the runnable example for us to verify.

Comment: s is missing in the sum

Comment: For the record I tried to delete this question after the answer since it's not really useful but S.O. disallowed it

Comment: @Antoine, it's OK. it will be deleted after review.

Answer (score 7):

You need to write `timeCompletedInSeconds` instead of `timeCompletedInSecond` at line 6. You are missing the `s` at the end, that's why you're getting `undefined + 3 = NaN`.

Comment: Unreal, I couldn't see it in WebStorm, thanks